# adding openid to html page

Tags: html, openid

Is adding something like  below to my site (for ex,my site is called mmmm.com) will work ?

```
 <link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://mmmm.myopenid.com">
```

I'm looking for simple stuff,that allows users to first register with their existing openid and then login to my site.
There is lot of documents - but im confused.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set up OpenID log in functionality on your own web site, for other people to log in, `openid.delegate` has nothing to do with what you are looking for. It is a mechanism to allow *you* to use an OpenID under your domain when logging in to *other websites*.

What you are looking for isn't trivial. You would have to set up an authentication system based on OpenID, in a server side language like PHP or ASP.NET.

See http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries for a list of libraries to help with the task.